# Linux freezing guess: keyboard & mouse (ArchLinux and Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, freeze

Linux on my PC is freezing a few seconds after startup. I am unable to use the mouse / keyboard. Neither Ubuntu nor Arch do anything after a few seconds. Windows has been running fine for years now.

Found so far:

- When I installed ArchLinux, every time I would fire up my PC it would start filling the console with these characters: ^@6^@6^@6^@6^@6... I had to press half the keyboard for it to go away. I think this has to do with the underlying Linux not with a specific distro.
- When the PC starts and I don't touch anything It won't freeze. I let it on untill I had to relogg, I was able to log in (Keyboard worked). Mouse was moving but I couldn't click anything. Shortly after keyboard was not usable anymore.

I have:

- Unplugged the Keyboard and plugged it into different USB hubs.
- USB Keyboard & mouse (Logitech G710+, Logitech G500) both with cable.
- Asus Rampage 2 Extreme motherboard (http://www.asus.com/ROG_ROG/RAMPAGE_II_EXTREME/)
- Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, and ArchLinux (used gnome and K).
- Keyboardlayout: Swiss German with Sun Accent
- Tryed another usb and a PS/2 Keyboard
- No USB 3 on my Mainboard
- The Keyboard is plugged directly into the motherboard, changed to different USB ports already.
- Enabled legacy keyboard support
- Turned EHCI off

I can't test things on Linux because it will freeze shortly after start (after the GUI loaded) whatsoever I have access to the drive.

Comment: Do you have a spare keyboard to test with and see if the issues persist?

Comment: Yes I have and I will do it, but I will only be able to test on Ubuntu 14.04 (just freshly installed it)

Comment: How did you go about installing Linux is Linux always freezes? Usually the installer processes themselves run from inside a Linux environment. Knowing this might help narrow down what is triggering your issues.

Comment: At what point in the boot is it freezing? After or before tho graphical login screen shows up?

Comment: The installation of ubuntu went without a problem, arch showed the issue in the boot screen (the endless key stroking) it shows up after the ui loaded. I log directly into the system no login screen. I don't get key stroking in normal apps only in the arch login, boot screen and ubuntu when I switch to F1 cobsole view

Comment: Hmmm ... after the GUI starts sounds more like a video problem that a keyboard-mouse one as in this originally sounded like. What video card are you running and what drivers did go with when installing?

Comment: I have a 580 GTX with the open source drivers comming with ubuntu. Was not able to change anything because it keeps freezing after start. It takes a couple of seconds before freeze, but I don't think it is gfx related since sometimes I can still use the keyboard while my mouse is not usable anymore. Also I can play all games on the secondary windows installation.

Comment: Arch Linux is the *devil*'s distro.

Comment: Cause of the problem might be some usb wifi adapter if you are using one as in my case but haven't any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have something funky going on with you USB bus and keyboard. Here are some steps to find the culprit. You may find more than one of these addresses the problem.

1. Try a different keyboard.
2. If this system has a PS/2 port, try a non-USB keyboard.
3. Make sure you aren't using a USB3 port for your keyboard.
4. Plug the keyboard directly into the system, not through a USB hub. Those tend to introduce errors in the device detection routines on first boot.
5. Check you BIOS for the settings involving USB keyboard support: specifically toggle the one about *Legacy Keyboard Support*. It may be called something different in your BIOS, but try toggling anything along those lines.
6. If you have an option for it, change the USB bus mode in your BIOS. Some systems have an option to run in UHCI, EHCI or OHCI modes. Try a different mode.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 did it all. Tinkering with bios right now. And it seems to run stable now, will update in a few minutes and mark the answer if it has stopped freezing. €: nevermind it keeps freezing. But I could use the system after I turned BIOS EHCI hand-off off. Legacy usb support is on. Still looking for a solution

Answer (score -1):

You could try disabling `evdev` in X11, or try to login via `ssh` and look in X11's logs for suspicious things.

Answer (score -1):

After installation add you user to the plugdev group to use Solaar as non-root user:

```
# gpasswd -a $USER plugdev
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question above? Can you elaborate?